# How to prevent collisions when training multiple models in parallel with PyTorch Lightning + multiprocessing?

Tags: pytorch, multiprocessing, pytorch-lightning

I am training thousands of small, slightly different models with PyTorch Lightning.  When I try to do the training in parallel using multiprocessing, the training processes seem to collide.  The first symptom was different models applying early stopping at the exact same step.  I confirmed that something was wrong: the contents of metrics.csv for the different models was exactly the same.

Things I've tried:

- setting the `dirpath` argument to `ModelCheckpoint` to be a folder unique to each model
- setting the `default_root_dir` argument to `Trainer` to be a folder unique to each model

Neither of these seem to solve the issue.
When I remove multiprocessing and train my small models serially, I have no issues at all.